# How can I search for multiple items in a "any" function: haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Right now I have this piece of code\

```
filter (any (=='a')) [String]
-- [String] is just any string list
```

if you can't tell this just filters for anything in the string containing 'a'. what I want to know is how can I search for multiple characters? if I try making a string/[char] then I get an error because of the inputs that the any function takes. How can I get around this, because for my purposes I will always have a unknown amount of chars, so I need a way to feed multiple characters into this function. Thank you.

Comment: What strings do you want to retain? Those that have either 'a' or 'b'? Those that have both 'a' and 'b'? Something else?

Comment: will ness it's similar but it has t be within the filter function which changes it a good amount

Comment: I found an answer using some parts of the answers left for me, so thanks for that. I found that `filter (any ('elem' "abc")) ["abc","and","kb",...]` worked as intended. I can't answer my own question so if anybody can copy this into an answer that would be nice. TY. ps: the single quotes around elem are graves.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `elem` to check if something is an element of a list.

```
filter (`elem` ['a','e','i','o','u']) "hello world!"
-- or
filter (`elem` "aeiou") "hello world!"
```

This is equivalent to using an explicit lambda:

```
filter 
   (\x -> x=='a' || x=='e' || x=='i' || x=='o' || x=='u')
   "hello world!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider, a function like `a -> [a] -> Bool` because you are searching for a function, which checks for a character in a list.

So the answer is:

```
filter (\x -> elem x [1..3]) [1..10]
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative:

```
containsVowels :: Foldable t => t Char -> Bool
containsVowels = any (\ch -> (ch ==) `any` vowels)
    where vowels = "aeiou"
```

If *any* character in a string equal *any* of the characters in `vowels`, the answer is `True`.